# Add "Improve edit" option to wiki edit reviews

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

Subj, for the same reasons we have it for normal suggested edits: if the edit is good, but *not quite good enough*.

I don't yet see a use case for "Reject and edit".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see these options for post edits because you can edit them straight. Basically, this is implemented as: 1) approve the suggested edit; 2) immediately make a further edit yourself. This even shows in the revision list ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34254033/revisions)). Reviewing and editing posts are both obtained at 2,000 rep.

For the tag edits, on the other hand, 5k is required to review (approve/reject), but 20k to edit instantly, therefore you can't actually improve or reject'n'edit until you reach 20k, so you have those options hidden until then.

Of course, nothing stops you from suggesting your improvement independently. But you can only do so after the current edit is decided upon (before that, you see "edit pending" instead of the "edit" link in the tag wiki UI). This is done to avoid conflicting changes.

Comment: The [declined suggested edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/42155) is "the first way around this that comes to mind". Okay, lemme formulate it like this to show how it's relevant:

"Theoretically, nothing stops me from suggesting my improvement independently. So, why not make the "Improve edit" button function like this instead?"

And the edit shows why this wouldn't work which is far from being obvious.

Comment: I initially wanted to post the question as a comment but then figured out the answer and decided to "cut the middleman" and go straight for the edit.

Comment: Sure, but tag wikis editing wasn't the point of your question - you know how to edit? Or it was?

Comment: The root problem I'm facing is handling a case where "the edit is good, but not quite good enough". So, I'm interested in anything that facilitates that goal. The usual way is deliberately barred - okay. Now, are there any other ways? Maybe there's still room for improvement in achieving the stated goal?

Comment: Hm. Ok, it won't really harm, so you can suggest it again.